# Unable to Install glpk-hs

Tags: haskell, glpk

I've installed the Haskell Compiler and glpk-hs using the instructions [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Linux_OS). Further, I've used `cabal install glpk-hs` to install required files in an attempt to compile a Haskell Program.

However, the cabal installation of glpk is not working. The following message keeps popping up:

> Resolving dependencies...
>
> Configuring glpk-hs-0.5...
>
> Failed to install glpk-hs-0.5
>
> Build log :
>
> cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/cr/9f1ltj7d4b31hmkfn03hjl_r0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-12521/glpk-hs-0.5'
>
> Configuring glpk-hs-0.5...
>
> cabal.real: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
>
> - Missing C library: glpk
>
> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
>   provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
>   already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
>   --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
>   cabal:
>
> Leaving directory '/var/folders/cr/9f1ltj7d4b31hmkfn03hjl_r0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-12521/glpk-hs-0.5'
>
> cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   glpk-hs-0.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
>
> ExitFailure 1

As above, I have tried both installing glpk in a nonstandard location and the standard location, but in all cases, has been unable to find the glpk.

The [glpsol solver](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Using_GLPSOL), which uses GLPK is installed though, as it shows the version of which it is currently running: `GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.62`

Comment: C dependencies are typically detected via `pkg-config`. Does `pkg-config` know about glpk? What does `pkg-config --modversion glpk` say? You might consider searching for an appropriate `*.pc` file on your hard drive -- e.g. look through the output of `locate '*.pc'` for something that looks glpk-related -- and make sure the directory that file is in is on your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried the `pkg-config --modversion glpk`, and it said that the command was not found. I also attempted the `locate '*.pc'`, and looked for something related to glpsol or glpk, and there was nothing. Do you think it's a problem with `pkg-config`?

Comment: Perhaps not. I just checked the cabal file for glpk-hs, and it uses `extra-libraries`, not `pkgconfig-depends`. So my previous comments about pkg-config are probably a red herring. (Sorry.)

Comment: Followup question: can `ld` find your glpk library? (Can you build a C program that uses glpk?)

Comment: No worries. Hm, I'm having trouble testing the `ld` finding the glpk, as I'm not too familiar with C. Though going by the [glpsol](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Using_GLPSOL) (command line solver), command line recognizes the GLPK package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! `hmatrix-glpk` had the extra directories for OS X in the .cabal file:

```
if os(OSX)
     extra-lib-dirs: /usr/lib
     extra-lib-dirs: /opt/local/lib/
     include-dirs: /opt/local/include/
     extra-lib-dirs: /usr/local/lib/
     include-dirs: /usr/local/include/
     if arch(i386)
         cc-options: -arch i386
```

Copying this into the `glpk-hs.cabal` allows the installation to work.